# How to round down Values in Spark sql

Tags: java, floating-point, apache-spark-sql, double

I am querying a postgres sql using the following query. I need to ***round down*** the value of  `min(months_between(current_date,somedate))`

for ex: `13.83` should be`13` and not `14`, even `13.9` should be `13` as well. Is there any function that can round down this value in`sparksql`? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `floor()` function. It rounds down its argument.

Note that `floor(x)` gives the largest integer ≤x. So `floor(5.8)` returns 5, but `floor(-5.8)` return -6. If your values may be negative and you want to round them towards 0, you must test their sign and use either `floor()` or `ceil()` (that rounds to the upper value).

Also note that casting a float to an int with `int()` rounds it towards zero whatever its sign. Not sure of the actual behavior in spark-sql, but it may solve also your problem.

Comment: Yes `floor()` fuction was exactly what was needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the `floor` function, reference this link:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#floor